# Why the upvoted non-wiki answers have +0 reputation instead of +10?

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, reputation, votes

It seems that there is an issue with votes/reputation on Programmers.SE (don't know if there is the same issue on other SE websites).

I've recently answered two questions and my answer had one up-vote each, but the up-vote is not reflected in my profile. The reputation remains the same as before, and "votes" display is weird.

Here's a screenshot:

[image]

You can see that for non-wiki questions and my non-wiki answers, for both answers the reputation has +0 instead of +10.

The links to the answers are:

- [Are Subject specific programing books a good idea](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/73009/are-subject-specific-programing-books-a-good-idea/73030#73030)
- [What best practices should be employed in a PHP login script?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/73024/what-best-practices-should-be-employed-in-a-php-login-script/73042#73042)

What's happening?

---

**Update:** it seems that the same problem affects [another answer](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/72967/i-want-to-create-a-software-company-what-are-the-basic-things-that-i-should-know/72969#72969). With 34 upvotes, there are 215 reputation points (15 as accepted answer) instead of 355.

It makes me think about another point. At the beginning, I published this last answer as a community wiki (see edits history). But it didn't work, i.e. the answer was displayed as a non-wiki. Then, I edited the answer, without checking the wiki checkbox again. May it be that it affected every other answer, so now, every answer I write is treated as wiki, while being displayed as non-wiki?

Comment: How do you have 99 unviewed inbox notices!?

Comment: @NickC: it happens regularly to me that I get 60 to 90 inbox notifications. It's not because I'd come back from a long period of inactivity, it's probably an internal bug, as I get notifications for things already read (sometimes days ago). Happens maybe 3 or 4 times a year.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It sounds like you hit the daily reputation limit.

Comment: Thank you. I've forgotten about this limit. Can you add `status-bydesign` tag to my question? Thanks.